# Merge 2 arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

This seems simple yet I cannot figure it out. I need to return an array merge for 2 arrays, they are not exactly the same and one is a global multidimensional array.

```
global $animals;

$array1 = array('dogs' => __('Dogs'), 'cats' => __('Cats'));  //localized
$array2 = $animals;  //not localized

the var_dump of $array2 is:

array
  'ducks' => 
    array
      'width' => int 350
      'height' => int 350
      'crop' => boolean true
  'cows' => 
    array
      'width' => int 750
      'height' => int 150
      'crop' => boolean true
```

I need to `$merge = array_merge($array1, $array2);` to return  an array like this.

```
array('dogs' => __('Dogs'), 'cats' => __('Cats'), 'ducks', 'cows');
```

But im getting all sorts of weird results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$merge = array_merge($array1, array_keys($array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$animalNames = array_keys($animals);
```